# Using exp() in axis cs

Tags: tikz-pgf

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  clip=false,
  ymin=0,
  xmin=0,
  ymax=1.05,
  xmax=10.3,
  xtick={2, 4, 6, 8, 10},
  ytick={0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0},
]
\addplot+[mark=none,domain=0:10] {exp(x)/(1+exp(x))};
\draw[fill] (axis cs:{2,exp(2)/(1+exp(2))}) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[below right] {$\left( 2, 0.881\right)$};
\node [rotate = 90,left] at (axis cs: -2.5, 0.8) {$\dfrac{e^{|s_1^{(i)} - s_2^{(i)}|}}{1+e^{|s_1^{(i)} - s_2^{(i)}|}}$};
\node [below] at (axis cs: 6, -0.08) {$|s_1^{(i)} - s_2^{(i)}|$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Now remove the line

```
\draw[fill] (axis cs:{2,exp(2)/(1+exp(2))}) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[below right] {$\left( 2, 0.881\right)$};
```

Suddenly the graph appears. Why is it that `(axis cs:{2,exp(2)/(1+exp(2))})` isn't being interpreted correctly? If I were to change `(axis cs:{2,exp(2)/(1+exp(2))})` to `(axis cs:2,0.881)`, it plots the point in the correct area, but I would rather have it exact than approximated.

Comment: This is because `{2,exp(2)/(1+exp(2))}` is parsed to `20.88078`.

Comment: @hooy Why is this? Is this talked about in the `pgfplots` manual?

Comment: I haven't seen it explicitly mentioned, but it seems as if the parser just concatenates the result from before the comma and the result after, as it evaluates them separately. You can also get the correct result with `{2,",",exp(2)/(1+exp(2))}` although that is not intuitive, and kind of "hackish".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key was `cs:2,{exp(2)/(1+exp(2))}` rather than `cs:{2,exp(2)/(1+exp(2))}`, bracing the expression for evaluation.  At hooy,s suggestion, the outer braces after `cs:` were also not needed (and thus removed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  clip=false,
  ymin=0,
  xmin=0,
  ymax=1.05,
  xmax=10.3,
  xtick={2, 4, 6, 8, 10},
  ytick={0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0},
]
\addplot+[mark=none,domain=0:10] {exp(x)/(1+exp(x))};
\draw[fill] (axis cs:2,{exp(2)/(1+exp(2))}) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[below right] {$\left( 2, 0.881\right)$};
\node [rotate = 90,left] at (axis cs: -2.5, 0.8) {$\dfrac{e^{|s_1^{(i)} - s_2^{(i)}|}}{1+e^{|s_1^{(i)} - s_2^{(i)}|}}$};
\node [below] at (axis cs: 6, -0.08) {$|s_1^{(i)} - s_2^{(i)}|$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. hooy states in the comments that `{2,exp(2)/(1+exp(2))}` is parsed to `20.88078`. Why is this?

Comment: @Clarinetist I'm no expert on the parser, but I knew that `exp(2)/(1+exp(2))` needed evaluation before parsing, so I placed it in `()` delimiters.  When that still didn't fix it, I added braces to isolate it.  That worked.

Comment: @Clarinetist I found that the parens are superfluous, and I only needed the braces.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You can actually just use `(axis cs: 2,{exp(2)/(1+exp(2))})`, that is, remove the outermost group of braces as well, as it is only the second coordinate that needs to be parsed :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your question has been answered already, so this is more of a tip. You can declare functions using the syntax

```
declare function={name(<list of vars>)=<function expression>;}
```

If you define `declare function={f(\x)=exp(\x)/(1+exp(\x));}` then you can use `f(x)` in the plot, and `f(2)` for the point. Convenient, and less error prone as well, than writing the expression twice.

I also demonstrated a way of having the number in the node label calculated and printed, again using the declared function. And I show how you can move `xlabel` and `ylabel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=exp(\x)/(1+exp(\x));}]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  clip=false,
  ymin=0,
  xmin=0,
  ymax=1.05,
  xmax=10.3,
  xtick={2, 4, 6, 8, 10},
  ytick={0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0},
  ylabel=$\dfrac{e^{|s_1^{(i)} - s_2^{(i)}|}}{1+e^{|s_1^{(i)} - s_2^{(i)}|}}$,
  xlabel=$|s_1^{(i)} - s_2^{(i)}|$,
  xlabel style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=north},
  ylabel style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=south,rotate=90},
]
\addplot+[mark=none,domain=0:10] {f(x)};

\addplot [mark=*,black,samples at=2] {f(x)} 
   node[below right] {%
     $( 2,
     \pgfmathparse{f(2)}\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}
     )$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]